# Extract links from a webpage and create a dictionary Python

Tags: python, http, url

Write a function that opens a web page and returns a dictionary of all the links and their text on that page. The links are the dictionary keys, and the text is the dictionary value.

Here's what I have so far.

```
import urllib.request as urlrequest
def getLinks(url):

   page=urlrequest.urlopen(url)

   lines = page.readlines()


   url_list={}
   for line in lines:
      if '<a href=' in line:
          removeHref=line[8:]
          end=removeHref.find('>')
          url=removeHref[0:end]
          removeHref=removeHref[end+1:]
          print (url)
          end2=removeHref.find('<')
          text=removeHref[0:end2]
          print ('%s \n' % text)
          url_list[url] = text



url = input("URL: ")
getLinks(url)
```

But when I enter a link and run it it gives me the following error:

```
 if '<a href=' in line:
 TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you tried with double quotes? Also, which python version are you using, works fine on my end

Answer (score 1):

You can't check for containment between `string` and `byte`, it has to be either `byte` and `byte` or `string` and `string`.

Since your webpage was returned as a `byte` object. You should do:

```
if b'<a href=' in line:
     pass # your code here
```